# How to stop Skype (Mac) from asking if I *really* want to close it?

Tags: macos, skype

At the end of each workday, I shut down my computer.

My instinct is to hit <kbd>⌃</kbd>, <kbd>⌥</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>⏏</kbd>, switch off the monitors and walk away.

However, Skype will prevent system shutdown by asking:

[image: Skype pestering]

Of course, with all monitors switched off already, I will not notice this until the next morning and it is driving me nuts.

Do you know how to make Skype just shut down (and up) when I tell it to shut down?

**Edit:** I am using Skype 5.1.0.935. To reproduce, open Skype, open some conversation (double-click some contact), then quit Skype using the Dock icon or <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What version of Skype are you using?

Comment: @Daniel open a chat or a call or something, then you will be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. Using 5.1.0.935.

Comment: That is totally weird. I am using 5.1.0.935, too

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Still using 5.0.0 though. Are you using non-standard (paid) Skype services that might be the cause for this?

Comment: @Paperflyer I have plenty of conversations open but it still just works. Strange thing though is that I remember having seen this window before but I don't know why and when.

Comment: @slhck: I just tried it on my home computer and it closes no problem. Wow, Skype is really strange.

Comment: FWIW, I'm also running 5.1.0.935 on OS X 10.6.7, and I can't recreate this either. I even changed a few settings in my Preferences, and nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it isn't much of a solution, but have you tried deleting the Skype app bundle, and deleting ~/Library/Application Support/Skype? It could be there there is a legacy config option in the config.xml that isn't in the UI anymore?

The config.xml is in ~/Library/Application Support/Skype/

Comment: This is as if a doctor would say "I can't fix this patient, so lets kill him and get a new one that works". But work it does.

Comment: Well yes and no. I started from the assumption that there was a legacy config option that was no longer present in the UI. You could have gone through all of the config files in there, so I did sort of use a circular saw when a hand saw would have worked I suppose. In any case, glad that it helped!

Comment: @Paper this is more like "We could perform hours of delicate microsurgery to repair this patient's mangled fingers, but he's Hitler, so we'll just take off the hand and be done with it."

Answer (score 2):

Our numerous customers called us with the same problem. Skype for Mac does not have a setting to turn off the log-off confirmation. I tried latest Skype as of today, version 5.3.0.1093, on our development Mac and Skype has the same problem there - it prevents Mac from shutting down.

By the way, the latest Skype for Windows has a similar problem on Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7. It cannot prevent Windows from shutting down, but it hangs and Windows has to force close it when shutting down.

One way of dealing with it is to turn off ALL notifications if you'd rather live without any of them than having this annoyance with Skype preventing you from shutting down your Mac without user's intervention:

Start Skype, then go to the file menu **Skype**, then **Preferences**, then **Notification** and check the **"Disable *all* visual notifications"** checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file transfer that hung in Skype, it'll keep giving you that warning dialogue when you try to quit.

I'm running an older version of Skype but the location of the transfers window should be:
**Skype >> Window >> Transfer**

Look through your file transfer history and cancel any that are hung.  That should take care of it.

Answer (score -1):

After using Skype, right-click on the Skype logo in the dock and click on quit skype.

Comment: Right, but that does not solve me shutting down the system and walking away. The point is that I don't want to explicitly quit Skype. It should just quit when the OS is shutting down.